# Zoo visitor registration form hidden member group

Tags: zoo-visitor, registration

Does anyone know how to have a hidden field within a zoo visitor registration form which automatically chooses which member group they will go in? This is my code, which doesn't work:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form error_handling="inline" return='supporters/support-us/success' allowed_groups="9"}
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="9" id="group_id" />
```

My default options set in the control panel under member preferences are for 'self-activation via email' and they go in to the 'members' member group. But for this particular form I want anyone completing it to go to a different member group, called 'supporters', group id is 9. At the moment they're just going in to the 'members' group after activating through their email, so I guess it's ignoring my hidden field?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine with your markup. Make sure that the Supporters member group isn't locked at the moment as only Super Admin's can assign members to that group.

I'm assuming also you have the closing `exp:zoo_visitor:registration` tag in your template.

Comment: The group is unlocked, and I have the closing tag in place. As I've got the 'Require Member Account Activation?' as 'self-activation via email', in the member preferences, I just changed this to 'no activation required', and it works, they go in to the supporters group, but I would like them to have to activate via email, and I also need this for the other register forms on my site...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with activation type settings, but my guess is that it's a limitation/bug when set to `self-activation via email`